# Cuál es el significado de la sentencia debug::println

Tags: php

Estoy revisando un código antiguo que debo cambiar a PHP/PDO. Encontré esto:

```
$query = "SELECT "--- sentencia -----";
$recordSet = $BD->dbLink->Execute($query);
if (!$recordSet){
    Debug::println("No se pudo ejecutar la consulta");
    return false;
}
```

Podrían explicarme qué significa el *Debug::println();*?

Answer (score 0):

Debug es una clase que tiene como método estático `println ()`. Seguramente esta clase mostrará una **echo** del string que introduzcamos entre los paréntesis. Aunque al no ver el método no sabemos cuándo se pintará a pantalla.
Tienes acceso a esa clase para poder mostrar el método?

Comment: En el código que me dieron no encuentro esa clase. Pero en el código se supone que al ejecutar el $query hay un error se ejecuta el if().